# when DataGridView ButtonColumn Clicked

Tags: c#, events, button, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

i have a dataGridView in my form , and i have a colum of button  in it. i want execute some code when only one of the buttoms clicked. i tried to do werite below code but when i clicked of the header of the columns, the writed code in block executed.
is the any one to help me ?

```
private void UpDatedataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(UpDatedataGridView2.CurrentCellAddress.ToString());

    if (UpDatedataGridView2.RowCount > 0)
    {
        if (UpDatedataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim() == "delete Record")
        {
            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete the record", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                UpDatedataGridView2.ReadOnly = false;
                UpDatedataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
                string number = UpDatedataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                da.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "Delete from tblKala where ID =" + number;
                conn.Open();
                da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                UpDatedataGridView2.DataSource = SelectData();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleting done !");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex and not UpDatedataGridView2.CurrentCell as you want to work with the cell firing the clicked event and not the currently focused cell.

Comment: can you help me? please read the following messages , Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following checks:

```
if (UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is
    DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
    e.RowIndex != -1)
```

The first condition checks if a user clicked on the cell which belongs to a button column, while the second checks if the click happened in a row.

UPDATE: I forgot you have to check the ColumnIndex: if a user clicks on the header row, ColumnIndex has the value -1 and therefore UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] throws an exception. To summarize, the final checks should look like this:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 &&
    e.RowIndex != -1 && UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is
    DataGridViewButtonColumn )
```

Comment: Hello to you; I wrote you idea to my source code but the C# compiler tell me that we don't have -1 number in our collection in other word the index number is out of range. I receive this Runtime error : "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: Hi, you should add the proposed checks between the first and the second "if" in your code. Please post whole method if the problem still persist and tell me which line causes the Runtime error. If you are testing your app through the VS debugger, you may find easier to debug it by selecting the "Thrown" option for the CLR in the Debug/Exceptions window.

Comment: Hi, I captured picture from my error , Please Download the picture : 

https://mega.co.nz/#!iFZBVAxR!NX7dsghmZ1G5hx2UvZp9PG89EB5mtW432z0Azu7gcnU

Comment: Thanks for the picture! Please add ColumnIndex check to the "if" clause as follows:

if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is
    DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
    e.RowIndex != -1)

Comment: Hi, I add columnIndex Check to my Conditions but again receive that error . I think the problem is the yellow Row and column in my DataGridView isn't Coming Into Account in the number Collection . I Am a little Confused And I don't know what should I do . :-(

Comment: Sorry, the order of checks is important, so please put e.RowIndex check in the first or the second place: if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn)

Comment: I put e.RowIndex check to my project but receive that error. https://mega.co.nz/#!OEp3FSRD!SwbweAI1PSrKCOtn6S6_CFb46Ih9ml-9trkOX7JG6Ic

Comment: You have to put it in the correct order, like presented above. You got the error because you checked the UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] first, and as e.ColumnIndex has a value -1 in your case, referring to the array of columns (UpDatedataGridView2.Columns) with the index value of -1 throws an exception.

I also updated the answer so please copy the second code snippet to your app:

if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && UpDatedataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is     DataGridViewButtonColumn )